# Format a date in a Power BI Measure

Tags: powerbi

I am using conditional formatting with a measure to display a header based on the selection of a slicer. This is the code that is auto generated with the measure along with some text I have added.

```
Select Year = "Displaying sales for quarter beginning "&SELECTEDVALUE('public all_sales'[sale_date], " Multiple selected quarters")
```

It results in this as a heading:

```
"Displaying sales for quarter beginning 1/1/2018"
```

I just want it to say:

```
"Displaying sales for quarter beginning JAN 2018"
```

I have tried adding a format mask, like this:

```
Select Year = "Displaying sales for quarter beginning "&SELECTEDVALUE(('public all_sales'[sale_date], MM-YYYY) " Multiple selected quarters")
```

However it does not compile as a correct format and basically I am clutching at straws.

Anyone with decent Power BI had a similar issue or know how to format dates within a Power BI "measure"?

Answer (score 0):

this one should work.

Select Year = "Displaying sales for quarter beginning "&SELECTEDVALUE('public all_sales'[sale_date], " Multiple selected quarters",Format('public all_sales'[sale_date], "MMM YY"))

Comment: No, it shouldn't. SELECTEDVALUE() can have 1 or 2 arguments, while you try 3.

Comment: @Pushkin, this fails sorry.

Comment: Hi, I altered the answer. Please, try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Year = 
VAR result = SELECTEDVALUE('public all_sales'[sale_date])
RETURN
    IF(
       ISBLANK(result)
       ,"Displaying sales for quarter beginning " 
            & "Multiple selected quarters"
        )
       ,"Displaying sales for quarter beginning " 
            & FORMAT(result,"mmm yyyy") 
        )
     )
```

Comment: Hi @Mik thanks, but I get an error --> A single value for column 'sale_date' in table 'public all_sales' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.